# How can I save a video recording when I lost the camera connection?

Tags: c#, video, windows-8, microsoft-metro, webcam

I’m using MediaCapture in a metro style app C# for previewing a webcam and recording video.
Failed method is called when I lost the camera connection. I tried to call StopRecordAsync() when I lost the camera connection but I have an exception cause the video recording device is no longer present.
Is there a way to stop the recording and save the recording video file when the video connection is lost??

```
public async void Failed(MediaCapture currentCaptureObject, MediaCaptureFailedEventArgs currentFailure)
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
    {
        if (m_bRecording)
            try
            {
                await m_mediaCaptureMgr.StopRecordAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // I have this exception : {System.Exception: The video recording
                // device is no longer present. is there a way to stop the 
                // recording and save the video file if the video connection is lost?!
            }
    });
}
```

Thanks,
Mona

Comment: Just a guess would be using CaptureElement & MediaCapture and trying to store data of preview mode in memory and later create your own file. I may start trying if no-one answers

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Did you try to store data of preview mode? How can we do it? Thanks.